# Accidentally overwritten value , how to get it back

Tags: matlab

My computer just calculated a value which took a few hours. I've accidentally overwritten this value. Is there a way to undo this ?

Comment: If it's not saved somewhere, nope. Always save important results before continuing.

Comment: I had to learn it the hardway it seems

Comment: I did too. :) Had a simulation running for a few days that only saved the final result, but I had power failure halfway and had to start over. Just be glad this wasn't a month-long calculation or more!

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely. The data may technically still exist in memory, but there is almost certainly no reference to exactly where it is stored, making retrieval impossible.

In future, consider saving your values to a file as soon as they are created. For instance, most of my Matlab scripts end in

```
save /path/to/experiment/folder/filename.mat important results
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file itself. There is an option: "Restore previous versions". When I did it, the matlab script had been saved every hour for the last 4 hours. I could recover it just like that :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! However, this is about a variable in Matlab, not about files. Moreover, whether or not there is a "Restore previous versions" option in a file manager depends crucially on the operating system, the file manager, and possibly other installed software.